# neither prefork nor worker settings are found in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf - why?

Tags: server, apache2

I've just installed Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu) on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system and can't see neither prefork nor worker settings in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. They are also not defined for default virtual host. Should I set them myself in apache2.conf like this?

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers 2
    MinSpareServers 2
    MaxSpareServers 5
    MaxClients 200 #must be customized
    ServerLimit 200 #must be customized
    MaxRequestsPerChild 100
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu 14 organizes all the module-specific configs in separate files under `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`, so the MPM prefork stuff is now located in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf`

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked for these settings within `/etc/apache2/conf.d/`?  It's likely that these settings are kept in separate included files to aid with packaging.

> Should I set them myself in apache2.conf like this?
>
> ```
> <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
>     StartServers 2
>     MinSpareServers 2
>     MaxSpareServers 5
>     MaxClients 200 #must be customized
>     ServerLimit 200 #must be customized
>     MaxRequestsPerChild 100
> </IfModule>
> ```

Yes, you can place them in apache2.conf (though do look for them in other files in `conf.d/` as mentioned above).

Your MaxRequestsPerChild seems very low - this can be in the thousands.

If you are running mod_php your MaxClients should be lowered significantly, unless you have many gigs of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My installation of Apache doesn't have `conf.d` at the `/etc/apache2/`. How is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, that is what I get for writing this answer without testing on 14.04.  I only have 12.04.  Either they have changed the conf dirs for apache or something else is going on :)

Comment: OK, we will wait for someone to clarify the matter :). Can you please elaborate on this `Your MaxRequestsPerChild seems very low - this can be in the thousands.

If you are running mod_php your MaxClients should be lowered significantly, unless you have many gigs of RAM.` ?

Comment: The default MaxRequestsPerChild is 10000 which means a process will only be restarted once every 10,000 requests per process.  Dropping this to 100 seems like it would only harm performance unless you're experiencing a specific problem such as a bad memory leak.  And for MaxClients, with mod_php you may need to lower this from its default because each process is so large - unless you have many Gigabytes of RAM.